# Collection of Various Color Matrices for Bitmap Manipulation

Tags: c#, flash, actionscript, bitmap, colormatrix

I've been messing around a bit with some low-level bitmap manipulation and having been creating some various color matrices to apply to bitmap data to add "filters" (for lack of a better term).

I have seen a number of tutorials online in C# and AS3 about applying various color matrices to bitmaps, but was curious if anyone simply had a collection of these color matrices that map to specific filter styles (black and white, sepia, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

quasimondo did a great job with his colormatrix

see it in action here:
http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000565.php
an as3 version here (methods' names are self explanatory :) )
http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000671.php

maybe you'll be interested in convolution filters ( rather than matrices )

here's a little "explorer" done by Sakri:
http://www.sakri.net/blog/2007/06/12/convolutionfilter-explorer/

still those are just 'tools', if you need to look into a given effect, you can try things like : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163866.aspx and grab the settings.

the good you have the values, the good thing is that you can inject them and see the result immediately. say you want to perform a [Sobel filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) ( which convolution matrix is [-1,-2,-1, 0,0,0, 1,2,1 ] and the same rotated 90° ) then you can copy paste the matrix values and try right away :)

Comment: I actually ported Quaismondo's color matrix class to Java (I'm using it for an Android application).  It is really well done.  However, I'm still looking for just a collection of color matrices at this point.

Those links you provided are helpful, but not entirely what I'm looking for.